# Ember: set array value for specific key

Tags: ember.js

How do I set a value for a specific array key in Ember?

I tried ...

```
var feed = this.get('controller.feed');
feed[i]['loadingFeedImage'] = false;
this.set('controller.feed', feed);
```

... but the template doesn't recognize the changed value.

I also tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
this.get('controller.feed['+ i +'].loadingFeedImage', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

Change the value like this: `this.set('controller.feed.data.' + i +'.loadingFeedImage', false);` (don't use square brackets).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript objects are reference based. So editing something in an array using it's reference updates triggers an observer update.

The reason your first solution does not work is because you don't use `set` at the second line.

Using ember array methods:

```
// assuming the array is an Ember.Array
this.get('controller.feed').objectAt(i).set('loadingFeedImage', false)
```

Make sure your array is an [Ember.Array](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html)

Your provided solution uses the private api. I would advise you not to use it.

Comment: What do you mean with private API and why should I not use it?