# Ember set value in object of array from Service

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to set the attribute 'show' of an object, that comes from an array which is served by a service.

the service (not the problem):

```
// services/events.js
export default Ember.Service.extend({
types: [
    {"code": 0, "label": 'Performance', "show": true, "css": 'warning'},
    {"code": 1, "label": 'Preview', "show": true, "css": 'danger'},
    ....
],
});
```

in my controller I have an action that should update the attribute 'show':

```
// controller
const { service } = Ember.inject;

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    eventsService: service('events'),
    ....
    actions: {
        setEventFilter: function(code) {
            ....
            let obj = this.get('eventsService.types').objectAt(code);
            // I get a proper Object here, that also has a set-function:
            console.log(obj);
            // this fails with 'Uncaught TypeError: obj.set is not a function':
            obj.set('show', false);
        }
    }
});
```

I've read the answers here [Ember: set array value for specific key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905879/ember-set-array-value-for-specific-key) , tried all the possibilities, nothing worked in my case.

What I don't understand is, that I can see the function 'set' in console, yet I still get that error:

[image]

Any suggestions? Anybody got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

I also tried:

```
console.log(obj.show);   // working! gives me right value
console.log(obj.get('show'); // same error (but with get of course...)
obj.show = false; // gives error 'Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the `show` property (of [object Object]) to `false`.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object inside the array:

```
{"code": 0, "label": 'Performance', "show": true, "css": 'warning'},
```

is not an Ember object, and therefore does of course not have a `set` method defined on it. You can set one of its properties by simply saying

```
obj.show = false;
```

Of course, this will not allow you to hang computed properties or observers from this object (or dynamically update references to its properties in a template), since as a POJO it has none of that machinery available either. If you want to treat this as an Ember Object, then it has to be, well, an Ember object, such as

```
types: [
    Ember.Object.create({"code": 0, "label": 'Performance', "show": true, "css": 'warning'}),
    Ember.Object.create({"code": 1, "label": 'Preview', "show": true, "css": 'danger'}),
    ....
],
```

This will make the sub-objects Ember objects, but `types` is still a plain old JS object, so you still won't be able to do things like

```
typeCss: Ember.computed.map('types', 'css')
```

so if you want that kind of stuff to work, you'll have to make the array itself an Ember object as well.

The reason that `Ember.set(obj, prop, val)` works is that `Ember.set` knows how to work even on POJOs. Note that there are circumstances in which the some Ember-like things **will** work on POJOs, but I would not depend on them.

As a side note, this behavior has nothing to with the object coming from a service.

Answer (score 1):

I found a working answer myself:

when trying

```
Ember.set('obj.show', false);
```

I received the error 'Set must be called with three or four arguments; an object, a property key, a value and tolerant true/false'

So I tried this:

```
Ember.set(obj,'show', false);
```

what turned out to do the job!

Still I'm curious why I've never heard about that different version of `set`, that takes at least 3 arguments....

I hope this is helpful to somebody else!